# loop not functioning correctly, partial data is being pushed to DB

Tags: javascript, arrays

My app uses a slack api that returns a gunzip file. The api is called for a particular date and the response is a gunzip file.
Then the gunzip file should be uncompressed into a .json file.
The json file will have around 1500 entries for that particular date.
Cumulative values of each field is calculated and the final result will be pushed to a database table. The final result that will be pushed to the DB is something like this:

```
{ 
 "date" : "2022-09-01",
 "number_of_users" :  1503,
 "is_billable_seat" : 1202,
 "is_active_ios" : 600,
 "is_active_android" : 400,
 "is_active_desktop" :503
}
```

The code for this is shown below.
An array with 4 dates is passed. In a loop the API is called and data is pushed to Database:

```
listDate = '2022-09-01', '2022-09-02', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-04']


for(let i=0; i<listDate.length; i++){
        
        let arr = []; let data_to_db = [];
        
        let date = listDate[i]

        let URL = `${process.env.slackapi}?type=member&date=${date}&pretty=1`;

        request(URL, {     //fetch slack data from API
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  process.env.accesstoken,
        }})
            .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
            .pipe(
            concat(async (stringBuffer) => {
                result = stringBuffer.toString()
                fs.writeFileSync('gzip-file-' + date + '.json', result, (error) => {
                    if (error) throw error;
                });

                const allFileContents = fs.readFileSync('gzip-file-' + date + '.json', 'utf-8');
                    allFileContents.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(line =>  {
                    arr.push(line)
                    });

                            
            arr.map(obj => {
                if(obj){
                    const myObj = JSON.parse(obj);
                    data_to_db["date"] = myObj.date
                    data_to_db["number_of_users"] = ++number_of_users
                    data_to_db["is_billable_seat"] = myObj.is_billable_seat == true ? is_billable_seat += 1 : is_billable_seat
                    data_to_db["is_active_ios"] = myObj.is_active_ios == true ? is_active_ios += 1 : is_active_ios
                    data_to_db["is_active_android"] = myObj.is_active_android == true ? is_active_android += 1 : is_active_android
                    data_to_db["is_active_desktop"] = myObj.is_active_desktop == true ? is_active_desktop += 1 : is_active_desktop
                }

            })


            console.log(data_to_db)

            connection.connect( async() => {   

                console.log("DB connected!!", date)
                   
                await pushSlackDataToDatabase(data_to_db, connection) //push slack data to DB
            })
    

           })
          );

        
    }
```

The issue is this doesn't push all the data to the database. It only pushes 2 days data.
I get all 4 days data from the API but only 2 days data gets pushed to the DB.
what is the error in the logic here?

Comment: `data_to_db` doesn’t appear to be an array of records, but a single record.  It looks like you are doing json.parse separately on each line of a json file rather than on the whole file.

Comment: If you are not using map to make a new array, you should be using forEach.